# Distinct Object using NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate, kvc

I have an NSArray of custom objects. Consider that the custom objects have a PageNumber property. I would like to filter my NSArray with a condition like "customObject.PageNumber is distinct".

I know I can loop through the array and eliminate object with duplicate pageNumbers. But is there any easy way to do it? I have tried,

```
[myarray valueForKeyPath:@"distinctUnionOfObjects.pageNumber"];
```

It is giving me the unique page numbers (like 7, 8, 9). But I want the custom object itself rather than just page numbers. Can any predicate help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a simple library, called Linq to ObjectiveC, which is a collection of methods that makes this kind of problem much easier to solve. In your case you need the [Linq-to-ObjectiveC distinct](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC#distinct) method:

```
NSArray* itemsWithUniquePageNumbers = [items distinct:^id(id item) {
    return [item pageNumber];
}];
```

This returns an array of objects, each one with a unique page number.

Comment: That's pretty Cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible with the help of `NSPredicate`

```
customObject=[(NSArray*)[myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.PageNumber==%d",pageNumber]] lastObject];
//pageNumber is an integer
```

The filtered array is an `NSArray` of your custom objects which is the result of filtering using the predicate. Since your page number is unique, it will return only an array of one object. We get that by passing `lastObject` message to it.

Refer:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001798-SW1

Comment: Sorry. My question leads to misinterpretation. I will update it. I want the array whose objects has unique pagenumber.

Comment: @Vignesh I am facing same problem.. Do u got any solution?